# Use animation images with canvas

Tags: javascript

so Im trying to make a card with JS and html canvas, but I ran into this problem and I cant seem to solve it thats why I am here asking for help. I want to make the image move animated. Thanks

```
var x1 = 0;
var y1 = 200;
img = new Image();
img.src = "images/WFlakeBig.png";

function init() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("greetings");
if (canvas.getContext){
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
setInterval(function(){draw(ctx)},10);
} else {
// canvas-unsupported code here
alert("sorry, can’t display the card");
}
}

function draw(ctx) {
y1-y1+1;
if(y1>400)y1=-200;
var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,400);
lingrad.addColorStop(0, '#4280c3');
lingrad.addColorStop(1, '#45bbed');
ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;
ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 600, 400);
ctx.drawImage(img, x1, y1);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
init();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "making a card". Be more specific with your question, provide context.

Comment: sorry, i meant to put greeting card, and the "WFlakeBig.png is a snowflake that I am tying to animate by moving down and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first line of function draw(ctx), instead of

> y1-y1+1;

change to

> y1=y1+1;

or I misunderstand.